# Installing LDPlayer with WINE fails with "unknown error"

Tags: software-installation, wine

I am trying to install LDPlayer using WINE. It's an Android emulator for Windows.

The installer starts, but just when it's about to complete I get a popup saying the installation failed with an unknown error

[image: The terminal and the error screenshot]

Other apps are installing fine.

I have an Intel Pentium 7th gen processor, DDR3 4 GB RAM, nvidia 720 2 GB RAM graphics card and a HDD

My wine version is wine-5.0

Is there a way I can install LDPlayer?

Comment: Hello. First go to the Wine support site and see if the app you are trying to install works with Wine or has any special restrictions. Not all apps run with Wine. Second this is not really a Ubuntu problem but a problem with Wine.

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details; you mention a screen shot but didn't provide link to one, and few details (what is '*ld player*'; you should assume we don't know as I don't, so details should be provided) so currently we cannot help anyway.

Comment: Ooops forget that one

Comment: you can use waydroid or use avd https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds

Answer (score -1):

I found [LDPLAYER](https://ldplay.mobi/en/) works fine only on 8GB Ram devices, if you use low profile device it won't work.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Your answer is quite unclear, unfortunately.  This question is specifically about running LDPlayer on *Ubuntu* using *Wine* to emulate Windows.  Are you running it in that environment, or just under Windows?  I have serious doubts personally that LDPlayer will run under Wine.  It also seems that you answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71690324/11810933) about running it on Windows, so I'm doubting that you understood this question.  If you really are running it under Ubuntu under Window, you *really* need to be clear about that in this answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, I rolled-back your edit here.  There's just no reason to provide a link to LDPlayer since users who are wondering if it will run under Wine will almost certainly know how to obtain the actual program already ;-).